# ssl_connect does nothing at all (observed in wireshark)

Tags: c, ssl, smtp, openssl

I have a code cross compiled to 2 devices. On 1 device the code works flawlessly, on the other SSL_connect does nothing. Info about both devices:

```
Device 1: (working) 
CPU: PowerPC @ 220MHz 
RAM: 128MB SD-RAM 
LINUX 2.6.24.6

Device 2: (not working) 
CPU: PowerPC @ 133MHz 
RAM:32MB SD-RAM 
LINUX 2.4.21
```

here's the code I'm using after sending EHLO and STARTTLS:

```
static SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL; 
static SSL *ssl = NULL; 

void CreateTLSSession(int sockfd) 
{ 
              int RetValue=0; 
        printf("CREATING TLS SESSION...\n"); 
        SSL_library_init(); 
        SSL_load_error_strings(); 
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); 
        //ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method()); 
        ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method()); 
        //(SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION); 
        //SSL_CTX_set_mode(ctx, SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS); 
        if (ctx == NULL) 
        { 
                printf("failed to initialize context\n"); 
                return; 
        } 
        printf("CTX created...\n"); 
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx); 
        if (ssl == NULL) 
        { 
                printf("failed to create SSL structure...\n"); 
                return; 
        } 
        if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd)) 
        { 
                printf("failed to bind to socket fd\n"); 
                return; 
        } 
        printf("SSL bound to sockfd=%d...\n",sockfd); 
        while (RetValue != 1) 
        { 

                RetValue = SSL_connect(ssl); 
                interpreteError(RetValue);
                sleep(1); 
        } 
        printf("OK\n"); 
}

static void interpreteError(int iError)
{
    int iRet = 0;
    iRet = SSL_get_error(ssl, iError);
    switch (iRet)
    {
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            printf("ERROR: TLS/SSL connection has been closed!\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            printf("ERROR: want read/write!\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
            printf("ERROR: socket not yet connect to the peer!\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
            printf("ERROR: want x509 lookup!\n");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
            perror("SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL");
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                    printf("ERROR: failure in SSL library!n");
                    break;
        default:
            printf("No errors\n");
    }
}
```

The socket is non-blocking. I'm using a while loop for test purposes. The loop will be substituted by "switch" later on.

The code output the following:

```
CREATING TLS SESSION... 
CTX created... 
SSL bound to sockfd=9... 
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
```

but never gets out of the loop.

I managed to connect device 2 to a managed switch and observe the network traffic through wireshark. To my surprise, SSL_connect() has no effect. The last thing shown by wireshark is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS":

[image: no handshake]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you check the return values for the SSL_Connect that is called in loop?

Comment: @Prabhu sure it always return -1

Comment: Sorry was that -1 or 1? -1 is error condition in which case you use SSL_get_error() to determine the actual error

Comment: @Prabhu it return -1 (minus 1). I edited my code. The error seems to result from the system, as I get `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`

Comment: ERROR_SYSCALL points to internal error condition. Can you use - ERR_reason_error_string() - to get further details of the error condition - https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ERR_error_string.html

Comment: @Prabhu @Prabhu `lRet = ERR_get_error(); printf("ERROR: %s\n",ERR_reason_error_string(lRet));` prints `ERROR: NULL`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50608/discussion-between-prabhu-and-hhachem)